# Searching for registries of persons who were born in Portugal or Brazil 1850-1930?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, birth-records, brazil, portugal

Are there good public sites available that have information about Portugal and Brazil ?

They don't need to be in portuguese, I just need information about genealogy and registries of persons who were born in Portugal or in Brazil.

I'm searching for registries from 1850-1930.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're looking for public sites that have Brazilian/Portuguese birth certificates. It might be better if you gave an approximate time period you're looking for records in. 19th century? 18th? 17th?

Comment: Unlike bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites here we are looking for a single focussed question to be asked so that it may often be answered using just a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 10):

My first starting points for answers to questions such as this are always:

[FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Brazil) This link leads to information on Brazil, but there is an equivalent page for Portugal. Both pages have links to relevant records online.

[Cyndi's List](http://www.cyndislist.com/portugal/) This link leads to links on Portugal but there's also a page for Central & South America which covers Brazil.

Comment: I'd also say that [tombo.pt](https://tombo.pt) is the best choice for finding birth records upto 1910.